# Binding data not shown in Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am not getting the value of attribute in jsp view. I am using JDK 9 and Tomcat 9.

In Controller I have tried:

```
public String girlsPageView(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("header", "Something!");
        return "girls";
    }
```

And

```
public ModelAndView girlsPage() {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("girls");
        view.addObject("header", "Something!");
        return view;
    }
```

My jsp has ${header} in body.

- Expected output: Something!
- Actual output: ${header}

Comment: Use Model in girlsPageView and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that the spring EL expression may doesn't get evaluated that can have one or more of the following causes:

- Application server in question doesn't support JSP 2.0.
- The web.xml is not declared as Servlet 2.4 or higher.
- The @page is configured with isELIgnored=true.

Comment: Yes this was the exact issue. Now I no longer need to add any ELI or jsp-config. I was using Maven's web-app Archetype and it uses version 2.3.

Comment: Changed web.xml header to 3.0 using `<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">`

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
```

after title in jsp resoved my error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "header", it shows header values. Try with a different attribute name.

Comment: Tried "message" as well. But that didn't worked either.

Comment: I got your message after my issue was resolved as header value had browser related values. Changed the attribute variable.

Comment: If you change as message, then in jsp should call as `{$message}`. I assume as your jsp files located in correct path.